# Adding constant to PHP loop variable

Tags: php

How to add something to PHP's loop variable and check the result? I have this simple code:

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo "Time: " . $i + 1 . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

The displayed result in the page:

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

But if there's no addition with 1, the result is correct. How to do this addition?

Comment: Use `echo "Time: " . ($i + 1) . "<br/>";`

Comment: Thanks. Why does PHP need brackets for this?

Comment: Because concatenation `.` operator has same precedence that `+` operator. So first will evaluated concatenation (because it comes first and expression is evaluated left-to-right), then `+`, which will result in casting operands to integer data type, and, therefore, `1` as a final result

Comment: @Alma Do Mundo No, the dot `.` and the arithmetic plus `+` have the same precedence, but the first dot is more to the left and thus is evaluated first. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: @feeela - just checking that while you've typed. Right, thanks.

Comment: Thank god the `,` has a lower precedence, and is actually faster here... :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You concat in your question use this:

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo "Time: " . ($i + 1) . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
echo "Time: " . $i + 1 . "<br/>";
```

to this:

```
echo "Time: " . ($i + 1) . "<br/>";
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does PHP require brackets for this?

Comment: brackets are always cleaner, in any way and every language

Comment: @ArthurN Because you also use string concatenation here and the line is interpreted as `("Time: " . $i) + (1 . "<br/>")` which is a non-numeric string casted to int (0) and a string starting with one casted to int (1), which is always one. It has to do with [PHP's operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) where a `+` and a `.` have the same precedence and the first dot is more left, so it is executed first. You could also use `sprintf( 'Time: %d<br />', $i + 1 )` to format your output. This way it is also possible to use simple templates.

Answer (score 1):

Put the calculation in brackets:

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    echo "Time: " . ($i + 1) . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

While adding parentheses to give the addition a higher precedence is an option, the easiest way is to turn `$i + 1` into an expression, to be resolved to a singular value and then pass it to `echo`, using comma's:

```
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
{
    echo "Time: " , $i + 1 , "<br/>";
}
```

But the shortest way to write this is:

```
for ($i=0;$i<5;)//don't increment here
{
    echo 'Time: ', ++$i, '<br/>';//increment here, and make sure to pre-increment
}
```

Or, more readable (and IMHO therefore better):

```
for($i=1;$i<6;$i++)
{//start with one, so you needn't increment in the loop body!
    echo 'Time: ', $i, '<br/>';
}
```

Leaving out conactenation is marginally faster, but you'll hardly notice that. It's just an alternative. Think of the two options as this (if you're familiar with C++):

```
int i = 0;
std::stringstream toPrint;//create string-stream
toPrint << "Time: " << ++i << "<br/>";//pass substrings/int chunks to stream
std::COUT << toPrint.str();//create single string, and pass to output-stream
```

But that's just silly, considering you're actually creating a stream, just to pass your substrings/ints to, only to pass the resulting string to the output stream. You might as well pass all chunks to the output stream directly:

```
std::<COUT << "Time: " << ++i << "<br/>"; //pass string, int and string to output
```

Think of `echo` as a language construct (which it is) that is your access-point to the `STDOUT` stream. Whe concatenate a string manually, of you can just pass it to the stream as-is? without any overhead?

---

As an asside, you can get the output you need in just 2 lines of code, without (explicitly) looping and incrementing a variable:

```
$vals = range(1,5);//create array 1, 2,3, 4, 5
//repeat format Time: %d<br/> for every index in $vals
vprintf(str_repeat('Time: %d <br/>', count($vals)), $vals);
//pass resulting format to vprintf, allong with the array of values
```

The output is the same. In case you're thinking about using this: *don't*. It's just for fun, and an example of how you can take compacting code a bit too far

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
    echo "Time: " . ($i) . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Why `<=5`? why not `< 6`. and why _still_ keep the parentheses?

Comment: As `<= 5` and `< 6` is the same, its usage is up to your personal favour.
I love parantheses, they ensure everything inside them is 1 part and some things are good to use even if not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to do something like this :

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $j=$i+1;
    echo "Time: " . $j . "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: this way the loop wont terminate

Comment: @mostafakhansa: Sure it will: `$i++` means `$i` will be incremented on each iteration

Answer (score 0):

Like DanFromGermany suggested, why not start with $i one higher than currently?

Also if you have to do calculations, the meaning of the var usually differs from it's starting point. So for readability and reusability do what Munjal proposed, but leave out the concatenation;

```
<?php

for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
    $laterTime = $i + 1;
    echo "Time: {$laterTime} <br />\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
$i++;
echo "Time: ".$i. "<br/>";
}
?>
```

or if you insist on concatenation

```
<?php
for ($i=0; $i<5; $i++) {
echo "Time: " .++$i. "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You're incrementing `$i` twice, so you'll get 1, 3, 5 as output, not 1, 2, 3, 4, 5. Your answer is just plain wrong